# How to display part of a line in a .txt file - C#

Tags: c#, list, arraylist, streamreader

I'm need of some basic help.
I've got a Folder, in which there is a File.
In the File, there are two lines, and the data in the lines is seperated with a "//".

Example:

> There is a folder at location @"C:\ExampleFolder_ABCD\"
>   In the folder there is a file @"C:\ExampleFolder_ABCD\ExampleFile_ABCD.txt"
>   In the file there are two lines:
>
> Name_1 // Description_1
>   Name_2 // Description_2

I need my program to display the **first part of each Line**, the part before "//" and only this part.
I've done some research, but am counting on some real-time help.

**Of course, any help, be good or bad, will be greatly appreciated.**
*NOTICE : This has nothing to do with homework. It conserns a project of mine, that will help me organise my phonebook.*

Lovro Mirnik

*If you feel like testing, copy the below code into a newly created Namespace, edit and execute it.*

```
string MainDirectoryPath = @"C:\ExampleFolder_ABCD\"; // Example directory path - Completely random name (100% no overwrite)
string MainFileName = @"C:\ExampleFolder_ABCD\ExampleFile_ABCD.txt"; // Example file path - Completely random name (100% no overwrite)
Directory.CreateDirectory(MainDirectoryPath); // Create the directory.
StreamWriter CreateExampleFile = new StreamWriter(MainFileName); // Create the file.
CreateExampleFile.Close(); // Close the process.
StreamWriter WriteToExampleFile = File.AppendText(MainFileName); // Append text to the file.
WriteToExampleFile.WriteLine("Name_1 // Description_1"); // This line to append.
WriteToExampleFile.WriteLine("Name_2 // Description_2"); // This line to append.
WriteToExampleFile.Close(); // Close the process.
//
//
// I would like to know how to display both names in a list
// without the Description part of the line.
// Maybe with a command that contains "* // *" ??
```

Comment: [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) should be helpful, along with a [TextReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textreader.aspx) (specifically [ReadLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textreader.readline.aspx))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some code:

```
StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(MainFileName);
            char c = Convert.ToChar(@"/");
            Char[] splitChar = { c, c };
            String Line;
            while (!Reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                Line = Reader.ReadLine();
                String[] Parts;
                Parts = Line.Split(splitChar);
                foreach (string s in Parts)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(s);
                }
            }
            Reader.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("Done");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find all you need here : http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-split

Around the middle there's a bunch of code splitting strings from a text file, you can use it after replacing the split part with something like

```
Regex.Split(myline, "\\\\")[0]
```

It should work like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

From your posted example all you would need to do would be to split each line on `"\\\\"` (you will have to escape the slashes).  Take the first result of the split and there you go.

Answer (score 0):

Another variation, using the Split method on the string object:

```
var result = myString.Split(new char[] {'/','/'})[0]
```

Just splits the string where it finds "//" into an array.  Then you pull back the first element in the array.